# Control event for UISlider when end tracking

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, uicontrolevents

I have a video player slider, I want to track event when user has started sliding video player slider and ended sliding video player slider. Also, I am tracking what slider value have changed. When slider starts and its value get changed I am able to track it successfully. My problem is when sliding ends I am not able to track it. Which `UIControlEvent` should I use for sliderEndedTracking?

I am using the following code:

```
// Slider actions for UIControlEvents
        playerSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderBeganTracking(_:)),
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        playerSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderEndedTracking(_:)),
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside )
        playerSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderEndedTracking(_:)),
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)
        playerSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(_:)),
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)


// Slider Actions:
        func sliderBeganTracking(slider: UISlider!) {
            Log.Debug("sliderBeganTracking")
        }

        func sliderEndedTracking(slider: UISlider!) {
            Log.Debug("sliderEndedTracking")
        }

        func sliderValueChanged(slider: UISlider!) {
            Log.Debug("sliderValueChanged")
        }
```

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390298/iphone-how-to-detect-the-end-of-slider-drag

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need to do CNTRL+DRG from UISlider(Storyboard) to your view controller. Here, Use '`Value Changed`' Event.

At this action you try any code just print something.

Secondly, Make outlet of UISlider as slider. than use following code ::

```
 self.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PreviewViewController1.sliderDidEndSliding(_:)), forControlEvents: ([.TouchUpInside,.TouchUpOutside]))
```

Try to print something now in sliderDidEndSliding() Method. Example :

```
func sliderDidEndSliding(notification: NSNotification)
    {
print("Hello")
}
```

> > By using these two methods you will get the actual prior implementation of UISlider.

Comment: Thank you so much. I started the search for this answer hours ago. Yours is the only thing that's worked for my Swift3 project.

I had to modify slightly:

radSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderDidEndSliding(notification:)), for: ([.touchUpInside,.touchUpOutside]))

Comment: Thank you very much! [.touchUpInside,.touchUpOutside] perfect work for when value DID changed

Answer (score 1):

`TouchUpInside` event is working for me. If you release finger from `UISlider`, the event is fired. 
Isn't what you want ?

Comment: I tried using TouchUpInside but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: The event isn't fired at all ? Are you dragging your finger out of the UISlider?

Comment: Sometimes it is working fine but sometimes it's not.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that. I think it doesn't work if you drag too much your finger out of the UISlider before releasing.