# How to detect when user finished moving Range slider in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, slider, uicontrol, rangeslider

I use this is [Range slider](https://github.com/AlexanderNaumov/RangeSliderExample) in my project. [How use it.](https://vimeo.com/155396036)

I want to detect, when user finished moving Range slider.
I tried to use function `SliderAction(sender: RangeSlider)`, but I get each moving points in the slider. I think I need to use this function: `func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch?, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`, but it is doesn't work.
How can I make it?

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390298/iphone-how-to-detect-the-end-of-slider-drag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To detect when user finished moving the range slider you can add a controlevent to your slider , you can add it programatically :

```
mySlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderDidEndSliding:", forControlEvents: .UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

then you have to do your logic the recieving methode .

```
    func sliderDidEndSliding(sender: UISlider) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 3 I used this:

```
mySlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderDidEndSliding), for: .touchUpInside) 

func sliderDidEndSliding() {
  // process stuff 
}
```

reading values is done with:

```
@IBAction func mySlider(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on this example [viewcontroller](https://github.com/AlexanderNaumov/RangeSliderExample/blob/master/RangeSliderExample/ViewController.swift), you should check the value `sender.selectedMax` value changed should be equal to the one you set in storyboard for that slider view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to **override** endTrackingWithTouch. It'll get called when tracking ends by the underlying machinery, giving you a chance to respond.

Be sure and call the super of this during your version of endTrackingWithTouch so the the parents classes can do their bit.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderDidEndSliding), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and add

```
@objc func sliderDidEndSliding(sender: UISlider) {
}
```